# cache (или нет) если я не авторизован

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Доброго времени суток. У меня есть сайт на wordpress.com, и заметил особенность, что если отключаю/включаю плагин, то у меня сайт реагирует на это только через минут 5 (и не только с отключением плагинов). И самое главное, что это только если я не авторизован. Эту болячку можно как-то решить?

Comment: Это кеш. Какие плагины кеширования стоят?

Comment: В общем, кеширование надо отключать до, и сбрасывать кеш и включать - после правок

Comment: Ну и про кеш в браузере не забывать. Ctrl+F5

Comment: Точно на wordpress.**COM**?   Тогда SO тут не помощник.

Comment: @SeVlad о, я и не заметил...